# SQL Server replication / mirroring without transaction logging?

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication

I'm new to SQL Server replication options.

I want to set up a system such that a backup database at a remote location is used for data analysis over some large set of data in the primary database. The analysis does not need to have access to live data, and I want to run this analysis daily.

I don't have access to transaction logging on the primary SQL Server 2008 database.

What is the best way to synchronize a primary database to a secondary one in SQL Server without using transaction logging?

Is there maybe another option I'm not seeing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do one of the following:

1. Some sort of automated backup, copy and restore.
2. Use a SSIS job to transfer the data from one to the other.
3. Use a linked SQL Server, and copy/update as appropriate.

The best solution though, is to use log shipping, scheduled once a day, if you can sort out your access to the primary database.